# Assert using Python- How do I check if the input is Integer or not?

Tags: python, assert

I wrote a function, which gets a number as an input.
For example:

```
def return_it_back(n):
    return n
```

I simply need to check if the input is integer or not with **assert**.
So, I wrote a **test** function:

```
def test():
    assert return_it_back("k"), "incorrect input"
test()
```

Python doesn't show "incorrect input". Doesn't the **assert return_it_back("k"), "incorrect input"** need to print the "incorrect input"?

Comment: In addition to Jan's answer: the function `return_it_back()` simply returns the input and does not care for the data type. Therefor, the `assert` is always true.

Comment: shouldn't the-
return_it_back("k")
without any Logical calculations such as == > < need to be False?

Comment: the doc for python 2 says that `assert` is equivalent to `if not x: raise AssertionError(y)`. This doing something like `if not 'word': print('Attention')` won't print 'Attention' because the 'if' evaluated to true.

Comment: You might *intend* for `return_it_back` to receive a number, but nothing about the function as written ensures or enforces that. You either check the a value before passing it to `return_it_back`, or you check *inside* the function to verify you received an appropriate value.

Answer (score 8):

`assert condition, message` is just syntactic sugar for:

```
if not condition:
    raise AssertionError(message)
```

In your code, `return_it_back()` just returns it's argument, so

```
assert return_it_back(n), message
```

is equivalent to

```
assert n, message
```

which is equivalent to

```
if not n:
    raise AssertionError(message)
```

so what's get tested is the truth value of `n`, whatever it is.

In Python, all objects have a boolean value - empty collections (builtin ones at least), the empty string, numerical zeros and `None` having a false value and most other objects having by default a true value.

IOW, unless `n` is an empty collection, empty string, numerical zero or `None` it will eval to True and the assertion will succeed.

If you want to test whether an object is of a given class (or list of classes), you can use `isinstance(obj, cls)` (or `isinstance(obj, cls, othercls, etc)`). Typechecking arguments is *usually* considered unpythonic (as long as the object acts as expected, who cares what type it is, AKA [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)), but there are a couple places where it makes sense - when sanitizing user inputs, at subsystems boundary, and eventually when it's garanteed that any other type will break the function one way or another.

Also, `assert` is a coder tool, not something to use for arguments validation - if your code is compiled with the --optimize flag for example assert statements will be ignored. IOW it's fine for unittesting (but there are more advanced tools in the `unittest` package) or debugging but not for production code. If you really want to prevent your function from accepting anything but ints you should raise a `TypeError` (or a `ValueError` if for example you expect a positive integer and get a negative one) instead.

Comment: @Basic that's why you shouldn't use `assert n` ;)

Comment: Then this isn't intended as an answer, merely an example of how not to do it?

Comment: @Basic cf my edited answer. The point of the first part of the answer was to answer your question as exactly as possible - you asked "why doesn't my assertion raise", not "how should I do typecheking" or "what tools should I use for unittesting" ;)

Comment: (Apologies for the confusion, I'm not the OP), but +1 for the additional info.

Comment: @Basic im the one being sorry for the confusion - should have checked - but if it helped you in any way then that's the most important part

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways, one might be

```
def return_it_back(n):
    assert type(n) == int, "Incorrect input"
    return n

return_it_back(123)
return_it_back('123')
```

This will obviously break on the second attempt.

---

You can also check the return value as in your attempt with

```
def return_it_back(n):
    return n

assert type(return_it_back(123)) == int, "Incorrect input"
assert type(return_it_back('123')) == int, "Incorrect input"
```

but this is redundant and therefore not considered "pythonic". Take the first alternative.

Comment: one usually uses `isinstance(obj, cls)`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Where's the advantage over `type()` here?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Normally, I'd agree. But here it looks like we're supposed to test if the type of the arg is exactly `int`, so `type` seems appropriate. OTOH, I'm a bit suspicious of the idea of raising AssertionError for something that _probably_ should merely raise TypeError...

Comment: @jan : in this exact case not much (except accepting `True` and `False` too, which might or not be a good idea but that's another debate), I mostly mentionned it as a being the prefered way to do typechecking in Python.

Comment: @PM2Ring agree on both points - as I said I mentionned `isinstance()` for the sake of completeness